# When I write something I want to start working in TeXworks, later my posts have been erased

Tags: xetex, texworks

When I write something I want to start working in the Text editor later, my posts have been erased and this text

```
  - This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./untitled-1.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
)
*
```

What's this ? What should I do :(

Comment: you show the log you get from an empty file, But the rest of the question appears to to be about how to save files in some text editor, but you have not said which editor that is?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle . Editor your texlive =texworks editors

Comment: Are you saving the .tex file first, before trying to compile it? The log file says that XeLaTeX is compiling `untitled-1.tex`. This suggests that you haven't saved the file (and given it a non-trivial name). TeXworks ought to be prompting you to choose a non-trivial name to save the file, but there's probably a way to sidestep this well-meant safeguard...

Comment: @Mico I have not chosen a nameThe  selected (untitled-1.tex )
So I must always choose a name it's true ?

Comment: @Almot1960 - Yes, you must choose a file name *other than* `untitled`, `untitled-1`, `untitled-2`, etc. That shouldn't be burdensome, should it?

Comment: @Almot1960 there is no hint in the question that texworks is the editor, i have used texlive since before it was called texlive but have never installed or used texworks

Answer (score 5):

Here's how to create a very basic document in TeXworks. First type a trivial document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

[image: image of TeXworks]

Notice that the title bar shows `Untitled-1.tex`. That means that the file hasn't been given a name. The asterisk `*` following it means that the file hasn't been saved. So use "Save As..." to both give the file a name and save it.

Here I've saved it as `test.tex`:

[image: image of TeXworks]

The title bar now shows the new file name and the `*` has gone, so now you can compile the document.

After the file name has been explicitly set, the file will automatically be saved when you try to compile it.